# How do I add a description above Logo in WordPress Customizer?

Tags: wordpress, customizer

I need to add a custom description above the Site Identity -> Logo section in the WordPress Customizer, for example "Use an image that is 250px by 250px."

(Image attached for more details)

My first thought was to look through this documentation:
`https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API` which I've used to add new controls,but since the logo already exists, it seems a bit different.

Do I need to hook into it somehow?

Any help would be appreciated.
[Here's an example of where I'd like to add the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQHKG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Update. The solution that worked for me was to override the logo. So for example:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'custom_logo',
        array(
            'description' => esc_html__( 'Use an image that is 250px by 250px.', 'namespace' ),
            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Primary Logo', 'namespace' ),
            'section'     => 'title_tagline',
            'priority'    => 8,
        )
    )
);
```